# Why can't they built motherboard into a single piece like monitor or mouse?

Tags: cpu

I mean motherboard has so many components:

- CPU Socket
- RAM slots
- BIOS Chip and Battery etc

Why can't they built motherboard with this said parts permanently attached to it? So no need to put CPU in CPU slot (or) So no need to put RAM in RAM slot.

Comment: Phones, laptops and tablets of all varieties already do this. The reason we have a type of machine that doesn't is because that machine is configurable to have exactly the parts you want or can afford and be upgradeable without throwing the whole thing away.

Comment: It wouldn't be very modular / upgradeable

Answer (score 3):

They can, and they do. They are called "[Single Board Computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-board_computer)", such as the Raspberry Pi. Although the Raspberry Pi was by no means the first of it's kind, as SBCs date back to the '70s.

Answer (score 2):

They can. For laptops they do. For desktops it doesn't make sense.

Modern laptops have CPU permanently soldered to motherboard. More and more models also have soldered RAM and sometimes even SSDs (Macbooks). BIOS chips have been soldered for years, I can't remember the last time I've seen a socketed one.

Why? Mostly because connectors and sockets take up precious space. Soldering components makes it possible to build thinner, smaller laptops.

Drawbacks: soldering makes it hard or impossible to repair or upgrade components. Faulty RAM? You can't just buy a RAM stick, you have to get a new motherboard (which costs *a lot*). SSD too small? Buy a new computer.